# Is there a way in .NET core web API to cancel a call?

Tags: .net, .net-core

We have a .NET Framework front end that makes a call to a .NET Core web API to retrieve items to show to a user. If the user makes a call for many tens of thousands of items and then decides to cancel the request it can eat up resources continuing to fetch items that we know the user no longer wants retrieved. Is there a way in .NET, once the call has made it to the service, to cancel the call?

Comment: Look into [cancellation tokens](https://andrewlock.net/using-cancellationtokens-in-asp-net-core-mvc-controllers/).

Comment: Are you looking for CancellationToken ?

Comment: (Copied comment from answer below) I was aware of cancellation tokens, but have not really used them. I knew I could use them within .NET Framework and .NET Core applications, but I did not realize I could pass them as part of the call to the controller endpoint. I'll try it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Look into CancellationTokens

In a sample Controller

```
public class SlowRequestController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public SlowRequestController(ILogger<SlowRequestController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet("/slowtest")]
    public async Task<string> Get()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Starting to do slow work");

        // slow async action, e.g. call external api
        await Task.Delay(10_000);

        var message = "Finished slow delay of 10 seconds.";

        _logger.LogInformation(message);

        return message;
    }
}
```

You could instead do this

```
public class SlowRequestController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public SlowRequestController(ILogger<SlowRequestController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet("/slowtest")]
    public async Task<string> Get(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Starting to do slow work");

        for(var i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            // slow non-cancellable work
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        var message = "Finished slow delay of 10 seconds.";

        _logger.LogInformation(message);

        return message;
    }
}
```

You don't mention what the front end looks like but you'll need some way to signal the cancel from the client request. An example might be.

```
var xhr = $.get("/api/slowtest", function(data){
  //show the data
});

//If the user navigates away from this page
xhr.abort()
```

Good examples here

https://andrewlock.net/using-cancellationtokens-in-asp-net-core-mvc-controllers/

And here

https://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/07/19/cancelling-long-running-queries-in-asp-net-mvc-and-web-api.aspx

Comment: If you're going to copy code wholesale from an article on the web, the least you can do is give credit to the author... https://andrewlock.net/using-cancellationtokens-in-asp-net-core-mvc-controllers/

Comment: Ya I was working on it, I am on mobile and word processing is slow. It is against the rules to only give a link out to other sites so I wanted to get the code examples up. Best scenerio is for OP to give an example of his code so a relevant sample can be written

Comment: I am aware of cancellation tokens, but have not really used them. I knew I could use them within .NET Framework and .NET Core applications, but I did not realize I could pass them as part of the call to the controller endpoint. I'll try it out. Thank you!